# Jquery code is not fully working for kendoUI grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui

I have a simple JQuery script that apply loop on Kendoui grid.

```
 function SelectALL() {
    var select_all = $('#select_all').is(':checked');
    $(".k-grid tbody tr").each(function () {
        var $row = $(this);
        var singleCheck = $row.find('.select')
        singleCheck.attr('checked', select_all);

    });
}
```

It perfectly works for two times. on third check it did not works and not show any error. Can't get any clue.

Thanks

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? And the elements with class="select", what kind of elements is it - select elements?

Comment: @SomnathKharat that's nonsense.

Comment: ok but Why it works for 2 times ?

Comment: @thebreiflabb I assigned class for each checkbox.<input type='checkbox' class='select' />

Comment: @SirajHussain can you put up a working jsfiddle which works for 2 times?

Comment: Depending on your jQuery version, you should use `.prop()` for boolean attributes like `checked`. If you have jQuery 1.6 or later that is.

Comment: @Shikiryu I dont know how to put code in jsfiddle.

Comment: @thebreiflabb I am using http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: Then you should change from using `.attr` to using `.prop` when dealing with boolean attributes. Regarding jsfiddle, you can simply go here: http://jsfiddle.net/ and you write your javascript in the bottom left block, your HTML in the top left. All the way to the left side, just choose the jQuery version you are using.

Comment: @thebreiflabb Thank you. it's 100% working on .prop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replced "attr" to "prop"

```
function SelectALL() {
var select_all = $('#select_all').is(':checked');
$(".k-grid tbody tr").each(function () {
    var $row = $(this);
    var singleCheck = $row.find('.select')
    singleCheck.prop('checked', select_all);

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Can you try ?

```
function SelectALL() {
    var select_all = $('#select_all').is(':checked'),
        toCheck = $(".k-grid tbody tr .select");

    if(select_all){
        toCheck.attr('checked', 'checked');
    }else{
        toCheck.removeAttr('checked');
    }
}
```

And if `.each()` is required

```
function SelectALL() {
    var select_all = $('#select_all').is(':checked'),
        toCheck = $(".k-grid tbody tr .select");

    if(select_all){
        toCheck.each(function(){$(this).attr('checked', 'checked')});
    }else{
        toCheck.each(function(){$(this).removeAttr('checked')});
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle? Much easier to debug when you show all your code.